# $_SESSION variable not updating every iteration

Tags: php

So I have this piece of code that is executed each iteration. The iterations are not ordinary loops but part of a series of ajax request iterations. The first ajax request determines a filename that is assigned to e.g $_SESSION['filename'] and then this variable is pushed into and array etc. Now the problem occurs when i have multiple files being processed.

It happens often that one of the filenames that is generated gets duplicated and inserted into the database which it should not.

First callback function:

```
    case 'upload':
...
$_SESSION['upload_filename'] = random_filename($alphas).'.'.$fileExt;
...
break;
```

second callback function:

```
    case 'insert_db':
array_push($someGlobalArray, $_SESSION['upload_filename']);
insert($_SESSION['upload_filename']);
break;
```

So as I said a new filename is generated properly like 70% of the time. I'm not sure why the old filename from the previous "iteration" lingers and $_SESSION['filename'] does not contain a new filename. I've tried unset the filename after insert() in the second callback function, but that causes a problem where no filename is available to be either pushed into the array or inserted into the database since what I think is that it gets unset before? I've also tried sleep(2) after the insert() and then unset but does not help.

Here is more of the code: http://pastebin.com/g4fereQx

Comment: Why go through the long process of using array_push(...) when you could just use $someArray[] = $_SESSION[upload_filename];

Comment: There are more filenames coming after the first one and I need some global array to contain them. The first case process the uploaded files and give also a new name. Now sometimes the name is the same on two iterations. Even though it should generate a new name like it does most of the time. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your code may not be executing the the exact order you think it is.
Its hard to say with the snippets you've posted though.

Comment: I've posted it in the pastbin link. The onComplete callback function is the function that processes each uploaded file in a list.

Answer (score -1):

could you show a little more of your code, like the ajax calls that send off the data and such. I know I've had problems in the past where I wasn't setting async: false in my ajax call and so it would try to process and act on information that hadn't properly been set yet